# How to index multidimensional numpy array with another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume I have following numpy arrays:

```
idx = [1,2]
A   = [[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9]]
```

I want to get `A[idx[0],idx[1]]`

`A[idx]` gets a slice. And I don't want to use `A[idx[0],idx[1]]` for clarity reasons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
A[tuple(indx)]
```